# Kubernetes doesnt create certificates

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate

I've created my certificate cfssl but when I generate my Kubernetes certificates with the file generated by cfssl, my Kubernetes returns the following error:

```
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "certificado.yml": CertificateSigningRequest in version "v1beta1" cannot be handled as a CertificateSigningRequest: v1beta1.CertificateSigningRequest.Spec: v1beta1.CertificateSigningRequestSpec.Usages: []v1beta1.KeyUsage: Request: decode base64: illegal base64 data at input byte 3, error found in #10 byte of ...| -d '\\n'","usages":|..., bigger context ...|,"request":"cat server.csr | base64 | tr -d '\\n'","usages":["digital signature","key encipherment",|...
```

I've tried without `$()` in the request field but it returned the same error.

my certificate.yml:

```
apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CertificateSigningRequest
metadata:
  name: rasa-service.default
spec:
  groups:
  - system:authenticated
  request: $(cat server.csr | base64 | tr -d '\n')
  usages:
  - digital signature
  - key encipherment
  - server auth
```

Comment: Looks like something wrong on how your CSR got generated.

Comment: i used this example https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/#create-a-certificate-signing-request, the "my-svc" i get using the command "kubectl get svc", the "my-pod", "kubectl get deployments" and "my-namespace", "kubectl get namespace", what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the following line:

```
request: $(cat server.csr | base64 | tr -d '\n')
```

This line contains a [Bash command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) that shouldn't be there since `kubectl` cannot interpret bash code.

I suspect instead of executing the [command of the example you followed](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/#create-a-certificate-signing-request-object-to-send-to-the-kubernetes-api), you copied the contents into a file.

Delete that file, run the `cat` command from the example and you will be fine, because the command will execute the substitution and fill the correct value in the `request` field.

The result should look something like this:

```
apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CertificateSigningRequest
metadata:
  name: rasa-service.default
spec:
  groups:
  - system:authenticated
  request: authUlRGTQpSVEZNClJURk0KUlRGTQpSVEZNClJURk0KUlRGTQpSVEZNClJURk0KUlRGTQpSVEZNClJURk0=
  usages:
  - digital signature
  - key encipherment
  - server
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it following way:

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl create -f -
apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CertificateSigningRequest
metadata:
  name: rasa-service.default
spec:
  groups:
  - system:authenticated
  request: $(cat server.csr | base64 | tr -d '\n')
  usages:
  - digital signature
  - key encipherment
  - server auth
EOF
```

This way it will not break or you need to place hardcoded output of `cat server.csr | base64 | tr -d '\n'` into yaml file.

EDIT:

I believe the csr you generated has some issues. You can run following three commands to check if you are able to create CSR

```
openssl genrsa -out admin.key 2048 
openssl req -new -key admin.key -out admin.csr -subj "/O=system:masters/CN=kubernetes-admin"


cat <<EOF | kubectl create -f -
apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CertificateSigningRequest
metadata:
  name: admin_csr
spec:
  groups:
  - system:authenticated
  - system:masters
  request: $(cat admin.csr | base64 | tr -d '\n')
  usages:
  - digital signature
  - key encipherment
  - client auth
EOF
```

Then check if `admin_csr` gets generated or not

EDIT2:

I used the same guide you mentioned in comment and I am able to generate CSR:

```
[root@ip-10-**-**-** cerificates]# cat <<EOF | cfssl genkey - | cfssljson -bare server
> {
>   "hosts": [
>     "ba***ta.default.svc.cluster.local",
>     "ba***ta-57f6c65474-8rdhz.default.pod.cluster.local",
>     "10.**.86.73",
>     "192.**.13.10"
>   ],
>   "CN": "ba***ta-57f6c65474-8rdhz.default.pod.cluster.local",
>   "key": {
>     "algo": "ecdsa",
>     "size": 256
>   }
> }
> EOF
2018/12/05 12:00:11 [INFO] generate received request
2018/12/05 12:00:11 [INFO] received CSR
2018/12/05 12:00:11 [INFO] generating key: ecdsa-256
2018/12/05 12:00:12 [INFO] encoded CSR
[root@ip-10-**-**-** cerificates]# ls
server.csr  server-key.pem
[root@ip-10-0-1-99 cerificates]# cat <<EOF | kubectl create -f -
> apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1
> kind: CertificateSigningRequest
> metadata:
>   name: ba***ta.default
> spec:
>   groups:
>   - system:authenticated
>   request: $(cat server.csr | base64 | tr -d '\n')
>   usages:
>   - digital signature
>   - key encipherment
>   - server auth
> EOF
certificatesigningrequest.certificates.k8s.io "ba***ta.default" created
[root@ip-10-**-**-** cerificates]# kubectl get csr
NAME              AGE       REQUESTOR                               CONDITION
ba***ta.default   6s        kubernetes-admin                        Pending
csr-9dcz6         59m       system:node:ip-10-**-**-**.ec2.internal   Approved,Issued
[root@ip-10-0-1-99 cerificates]#
```

Comment: i've tried with hardcoded type as you said and the same error occurred.

Comment: Did you tried with the way I mentioned in my answer?

Comment: @DanielPereira I have edited my answer please have a look.