# kubectl trying to create CertificateSigningRequest error :Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "tcsr.yaml":CertificateSigningRequest

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

i try to create CertificateSigningRequest

```
apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CertificateSigningRequest
metadata:
  name: vault-csr
spec:
  groups:
  - system:authenticated
  request: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURSBSRVFVRVNULS0tLS0KTUlJRklEQ0NBd2dDQVFBd0lERWVNQdHQTFVRUF3d1ZkbUYxYkhRdWRtRjFiSFF0Y0dWeWMyOHVjM1pqTUlJQwpJakFOQmdrcWhraUc5dzBCQVFFRkFBT0NBZzhBTUlJQ0NS0NBZ0VBdFJubkFQR2R4bG1xdjhMOW1Gc29YOXJuCk9JcTVGTJMZmRDelZCVEVUEV6TDgzSWFsT1cya2lrNWFRM282d2NSTmx1S3NzeUl1c0ZUSTFqR2djWjN0eXkKSDFqMlROMmNHMHp4MGVaYTJqK3JMVkkwSmVTdXFHNkdmY01rRzRudUhZSGJraDZUYmgyalc5S0RTUTVRekNzdwo0Rlg4bDZXVEVILzdSemgwNCt0RkdFamxVVktkakJYcVqMhBc0NqemJ2Sy9GaEhLRjJwRVpza1pSNWtCbC80Cm1KLxxxxJQ0FURSBSRVFVRVNULS0tLS0K
  usages:
  - digital signature
  - key encipherment
  - server auth
```

but im getting :

```
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "tmp/csr.yaml": CertificateSigningRequest in version "v1beta1" cannot be handled as a CertificateSigningRequest: v1beta1.CertificateSigningRequest.Spec: v1beta1.CertificateSigningRequestSpec.Usages: []v1beta1.KeyUsage: Request: decode base64: illegal base64 data at input byte 2432, error found in #10 byte of ...|ULS0tLS0K","usages":|..., bigger context ...|pPQotLS0tLUVORCBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURSBSRVFVRVNULS0tLS0K","usages":["digital signature","key encipherment",|...
```

what does it mean?

Comment: I managed to create it as `client auth` not with `server auth`. My `apiVersion` is `certificates.k8s.io/v1`. Don't know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is definitely wrong with your `request` line.
Your error goes from(most probably, am not sure!!, seems) from the wrong encoded data copy pasted data.

You can find really a lot of similar examples, like [Kubernetes doesnt create certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53616728/kubernetes-doesnt-create-certificates)

reproduced your minor example, seems everything work.
To reproduce I used [Create CertificateSigningRequest](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/certificate-signing-requests/#create-certificatesigningrequest) official documentation page

Small remark: There is a **v1** apiversion in official doc - I wasnt able to create `CertificateSigningRequest` with it, so I had to back to `apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1` one.

The error I received using `apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1`  was

```
error: unable to recognize "sr.yaml": no matches for kind "CertificateSigningRequest" in version "certificates.k8s.io/v1"
```

So, basically,

```
$ openssl genrsa -out vit.key 2048
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus (2 primes)
............................................................................................................................+++++
........+++++
e is 65537 (0x010001)

$ openssl req -new -key vit.key -out vit.csr
...
$ cat vit.csr | base64 | tr -d "\n"                                                                                                              
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
```

I manually copypasted key and put into the yaml using VI...

```
apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CertificateSigningRequest
metadata:
  name: vit
spec:
  groups:
  - system:authenticated
  request: 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
  usages:
  - client auth
```

result is:

```
$ kubectl apply -f sr.yaml
certificatesigningrequest.certificates.k8s.io/vit created
```

> request is the base64 encoded value of the CSR file content. You can
> get the content using this command: cat john.csr | base64 | tr -d "\n"

You can also use `request: $(cat server.csr | base64 | tr -d '\n')` instead of  copy-pasting plain text.. Just read info below plz..its important

[csr generation not working as per doc](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/90240#issuecomment-619129900)

> Similar problem had been vexing me as well. After some
> troubleshooting, it was observed the base64 and tr solution doesn't
> work well in an MacOS environment. Using the gbase64 utilities from
> GNU has a '-w ' option that will not line wrap. Once I installed gnu
> coreutils and used gbase64, the scripts worked as expected. The
> problem is related to 'tr' and line-wrapping using the original
> combination. Hope it helps future users who stumble into similar
> environment related issues.

Comment: thanks allot for the answer but im getting;
no matches for kind "CertificateSigningRequest" in version "certificates.k8s.io/v1"

Comment: Sorry, in the end I put wrong apiver in my last example. Just edited. Check.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but after changing I'm still getting error :
$ kubectl create -f tmp/csr.yaml
error: error validating "csr.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(CertificateSigningRequest.spec.groups[0]): invalid type for io.k8s.api.certificates.v1beta1.CertificateSigningRequestSpec.groups: got "map", expected "string"; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

Comment: found the problem! this is sick its should be : - system:authenticated
and not - system: authenticated   ( see the space)